# PHP - get blob image size - FPDF - getimagesizefromstring doesn't work

Tags: php, image, blob, fpdf, getimagesize

So I am using php/oracle to create a PDF via the FPDF class/plugin. I am using the Mem_Image class/script to add a blob image to my PDF, but I am having trouble determining the size of the image. I am running PHP 5.2 so getimagesizefromstring isn't working.

For the image it will have a fixed height that I am able to set in the FPDF class, but the width since it could be portrait - or - landscape image, I'll need to scale the image proportionally.

Comment: Hmm, you may need to write it out to a temporary physical file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`imagecreatefromstring`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) and [`imagesx`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php).

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I think when I initially saw imagesx I assumed it had to do with x-pos and not dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

getimagesize() does work with stream wrappers. Unfortunately, php://memory doesn't give you a way to reference it by filename. Either create your own stream wrapper that work smarter or use the [VariableStream example](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php).